# postgres, WHEN EXISTS to return column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql query something like this:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT r.name as name from downtime d, result r where d.status_id = r.id limit 1) 
THEN 'down' 
ELSE 'up' 
END
```

In this above query, if there are no match (0 result), it returns 'up' or else it returns 'down'. 
But I want it to return the "r.name" if there are any match.
SO this query doesn't work:

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT r.name as name from downtime d, result r where d.status_id = r.id limit 1) 
THEN r.name 
ELSE 'up' 
END
```

Any pointers how I can do that

Comment: please show full query

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should stop using the ancient and fragile implicit joins and switch to using the modern, explicit JOIN operator.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I end up using coalesce... btw can you please explain what you mean exactly

Comment: `from downtime d, result r where d.status_id = r.id` is better written as `from downtime d join result r on d.status_id = r.id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()` to return the first non-null value:

```
coalesce((SELECT r.name from downtime d, result r where d.status_id = r.id limit 1), 'up')
```

Comment: great thanks, this keyword I was not aware of... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To get value from a column you have to write
`select column_name from table where some condition` so if you do the following it will work.

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT r.name as name from downtime d, result r where d.status_id = r.id limit 1) 
THEN (SELECT r.name as name from downtime d, result r where d.status_id = r.id limit 1) 
ELSE 'up' 
END
```

Comment: @jarlh answer is more concise compared to answer above.